# Microservices communications content

Tags: microservices, messaging

So I was watching Jimmy Bogard giving a talk on [Effective Microservice Communications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHsVsbo_VOE) (Power Point available on [his GitHub](https://github.com/jbogard/presentations/blob/master/MicroserviceMessagingPatterns/MicroserviceMessagingPatterns.pptx)). One thing he mentions is that the messages between the services should be small, something like this (example from the presentation):

```
POST /dress
{
    "order": "/order/23"
}
```

To my understanding, this would be a link to where the full order details (which would be needed to perform any action on the order). So this raises two questions:

1. Does that mean that there would have to be an `Order` service, in which the order details are stored. And which all the other services, that needs to do something with the order, reads from?
2. If 'Yes' to the above, what is the advantage of this approach, rather than just sending the order information inside the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple potential reasons for doing so:

- The object has to be retrieved when the task executes. For example I have written a sync service where we would get a change notifications with a version ID and we would have to re-check if the object was still at that version.
- The object is simply too large
- The object is not behind a REST API (or otherwise not accessible by other services)
- The sender does not have access or the data is confidential

As you point out, the knowledge to retrieve that object now needs to reside with the recipient of the message.

Comment: So it would go something like the `OrderService` storing the order, but then also sending a request to the `DressService`, that this order needs to be processed. But the `DressService` would then itself request the data (perhaps via `GET`) from the `OrderService`?

Comment: Yes, you end up with an architecture where everything depends on the order service

Comment: Thanks. That seems a bit unhealthy to me...

Comment: The goal of microservices is not to have no dependencies, it is to have ownership of certain areas encapsulated in services. The order service will own orders and it will be the only service making changes to orders. It's better than a monolith where everyone has visibility into everything. Of course you could do this with a monolith and a lot of discipline also, but then you don't get to talk at conferences :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only provide a reference to the details, then you definitely need a service to provide the details. The advantages are:

- The message is small and therefore requires little network capacity.
- Consumers of the message will not have to be changed if a new field is added to, changed in or removed from the order.

I know you're not asking for downsides of this, but I never use this pattern. Adding at least some basic information about the order allows listeners to quickly filter out messages they don't need, without putting a load on your Orders service. Maybe it even allows part of your consumers to process the whole message without bothering your Orders Service, reducing coupling between the consumers and the Orders Service.

Also, if you have a lot of consumers, they will probably query the Order service as soon as they receive the message, putting a short peak load on your Order service.

In most cases I would go for a balance: include the information that most consumers are likely to need and include a reference for the other clients to retrieve the rest of the information.

Regards,
Quido.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comment. While I didn't ask directly, I am deffinitely interested in the downsides :-). I am still trying to get a grasp of this whole microservice concept.